# What is the best approach for designing Android client-server app

Tags: android, client-server

I am writing an android application that displays tickets, stored in a database on a server.
When the administrator adds a ticket via the web interface to the database on the server, a notification about this new ticket comes to the application, so that the user can open it and subscribe to it.
A ticket can also be closed when needed number of users subscribe to it. In this case,
in the application, the list of tickets should be updated - i.e. this closed ticket will disappear from it.

The estimated number of users will be from 1000 to 3000

Which is the best approach to use:

1. poll the server every 5-10 seconds using, for example, the foreground service, for new and closed tickets
2. use Firebase Cloud Messaging
3. a different approach
   ?

I thougth to use approach 1) but with 3000 users we will have 50 millions requests to the server per 24 hours. I really don't know is it ok for modern server or not.

Is it worth to use approach 2) in this situation, or maybe some different approach?
If you have link to material on this topic for beginners, it will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes this is a fine project for a beginner.

Comment: thanks for trolling, I'm not an absolute beginner in Android programming. But this is the first client-server app, yes